# (Jersey 1.11) Unable to compile class for JSP error in my dev machine (mac)

Tags: google-app-engine, jsp, eclipse-plugin, jersey

I am getting this error only in local dev machine (mac + eclipse + google app engine plugin:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:
An error occurred at line: 11 in the generated java file
The import **_** cannot be resolved

Line #11 is importing some internal classes and again this works fine in production. I am using Eclipse 3.7 with corresponding Google App Engine plugin on Mac.

I have been stuck on this problem. Please someone helps me!

Comment: It might help to show the package + class name you're trying to import, and the first few lines of the JSP (up through the import).

Comment: Indeed. How do you expect help when you don't even provide the source code where the error occurs?